# Dynamically generate dropdownlist on selection of list item using angular or javascript

Tags: angularjs

I have one list in html who has value from 1-10.
If user select 3 then i want to generate three drop-down list in html and need to append in html. And also need to generate id and it should have different id..that should also generated dynamically  also it has directives like ng-repeat to bind data  ....can you please help on ..i am newbie to programming

And i need bind data to list from web service response which is json.

Currently i am able fetch data from web service and bind to it . But not able to generate dynamic list on selection of dropdown list.

```
Example of List:
  <select ng-model="config.xAxis">
<option ng-repeat="key in keys" ng-selected="{{key==config.xAxis}}" value="{{key}}">
        {{key}}
        </select>
```

Can i use directives for that , if yes can anyone help me to create as i am not able to how to do it? or javascript option is better. Kindly help on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely create new directive as per your needs.
The official documentation is quite good. ([Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive))

If you overwhelmed by the documentation you can try other documentations available. ([Like this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mastering-angularjs-directives--cms-22511))

Before that, you can also explore already written open source drop-down directives. Like [chosen.js](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), or [jseppi](https://github.com/jseppi/angular-dropdowns). There are so many. Try exploring them.